# MongoDB : Error message if there are same value after update

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database in array like this :

```
MyDB = [
    {
      name: "John",
      age: "22"
    },
    {
      name: "Hilda",
      age: "23"
    }
]
```

I want to update the age with rules :

1. If, I pick Hilda with `.findOne()` method so that I can update the Hilda age and her name with `.updateOne()` method,
2. But, If I pick Hilda and rename her become John, it would be an error message because the name already exists.

I'm very new with this case. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be using unique:true for name in your model

Comment: What are your expectations?